# AutoCompleteBox issue when having multiple items with same values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, autocompletebox

My issue is that if I have objects with the same value in ValueMemberPath then the AutoCompleteBox selects the first item after it selects the correct item.
I've bound SelectedItem to a Property and I can see it get's fired twice if there are multiple items with the same value.

I've bound my AutoCompleteBox to an ObservableCollection of Person objects.

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName 
    {
        get
        {
            return Name + " - " + ID;
        }

    }
}
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <inputtoolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoCompleteBox" ValueMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <inputtoolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </inputtoolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
    </inputtoolkit:AutoCompleteBox>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.ID}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

My Window_Loaded looks like this:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        Persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "Person" });
        Persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Person" });
        Persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, Name = "Person" });
        Persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 4, Name = "Person" });

        autoCompleteBox.DataContext = this;
        textBlock.DataContext = this;
    }
```

When I write "Per" 4 items will be shown in the DropDown. Now when I selected the fourth, it gets selected and the binding updates. However it then goes back to the first item. Is this a bug or intended behaviour and can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: How is the user expected to be able to tell the difference here anyway?

Comment: Yes, I think if you could describe how the the user is supposed to select from a list of the same value it would be helpful.

Comment: Unless we get more information it's hard to tell. But If I understand you correctly this code here ValueMemberPath="Name" should be ValueMemberPath="ID"

Comment: @ Lasse: The user is able to tell the difference because I'm binding SelectedPerson to another control. This was merely an example (a bad one, I agree). 

@ingo: If I set the ValueMemberPath="ID" then the ID will be shown in my AutoCompleteBox.

The thing is, it actually sets the right SelectedPerson the first time but then it goes back to setting it to the first one in the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue.  I haven't tried it yet, but I found this link and it looks to have solution.
http://www.yumasoft.com/node/45

**Edit**
I just confirmed that this does work.

For the comments asking how the user will tell the difference.  The ItemTemplate providers more detail than is shown in just the TextBox portion.  This allows the user to decide which record to use.